# Populate textboxes with XmlNode.Attributes

Tags: c#, xml, gridview

I have Data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<data>
<album>
    <slide title="Autum Leaves"
        description="Leaves from the fall of 1986"
        source="images/Autumn Leaves.jpg"
        thumbnail="images/Autumn Leaves_thumb.jpg" />
    <slide title="Creek"
        description="Creek in Alaska"
        source="images/Creek.jpg"
        thumbnail="images/Creek_thumb.jpg" />
</album>
</data>
```

I'd like to be able to edit the attributes of each Slide node via GridView (that has a "Select" column added.) And so far I have:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedIndex = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
    LoadXmlData(selectedIndex);
}

private void LoadXmlData(int selectedIndex)
{
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.Load(MapPath(@"..\photo_gallery\Data.xml"));
    XmlNodeList nodelist = xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
    XmlNode xmlnode = nodelist.Item(selectedIndex);
    titleTextBox.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["title"].InnerText;
    descriptionTextBox.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["description"].InnerText;
    sourceTextBox.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["source"].InnerText;
    thumbTextBox.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["thumbnail"].InnerText;
}
```

The code for LoadXmlData is just a guess on my part - I'm new to working with xml in this way. I'd like have the user to slected the row from the gridview, then populate a set of text boxes with each slide attributed for updating back to the Data.xml file.

> The error I'm getting is Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at the line: titleTextBox.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["@title"].InnerText;

so I'm not reaching the attribute "title" of the slide node. Thanks for any ideas you may have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well yes - given your XML, the `xmldoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;` statement will give you exactly one node - the `<album>` node - and it doesn't have any attribute called `["title"]`.

You need to

- change the way you select your nodes; the `xmldoc.DocumentElement` corresponds to the `<data>` node, and it's `.ChildNodes` collection will include all the direct child nodes - which in this case is the one and only `<album>` node - nothing else.
- check for existence! (and not just assume it works...)

Try this:

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(MapPath(@"..\photo_gallery\Data.xml"));

XmlNodeList nodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/data/album/slide");

foreach(XmlNode xmlnode in nodelist)
{
    if(xmlnode.Attributes["title"] != null
       titleTextBox.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["title"].InnerText;

    if(xmlnode.Attributes["description"] != null
       descriptionTextBox.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["description"].InnerText;

    if(xmlnode.Attributes["source"] != null
       sourceTextBox.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["source"].InnerText;

    if(xmlnode.Attributes["thumbnail"] != null
        thumbTextBox.Text = xmlnode.Attributes["thumbnail"].InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Also you can call just `SelectNodes("//slide")`, if I'm not wrong

Comment: @marc_s  Hey, your explanation about xlmdoc.DocumentElement and code example are great. I changed it very slightly to get to work properly: 

 XmlNode node = nodelist.Item(selectedIndex);

        if (node.Attributes["title"] != null)
        {
            titleTextBox.Text = node.Attributes["title"].InnerText;
        }

Thank you Marc.

Comment: @abatishchev: yes you can - but it's not very good for performance and it will search for a "slide" entry anywhere in the document. That may or may not be what you're looking for....

Comment: @abatishchev: yes, the more specific you can be - especially avoiding any // in your XPath - the better your performance will be.

Answer (score 0):

`@title` is a XPath call for attributes, i.e. `"//slide['@title']"`

`XmlNode.Attributes` holds attributes just by name - `title`, i.e. `node.Attributes["title"]`